# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

High time to obtain some [pro tem mods](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/). [In short, soon 4 users will be made temporary moderators. After site graduation (or earlier in case of heavy moderation problems), pro tem mods will become regular users again and diamonds will be permanently given to 3 people selected in open election.]

Rules:

- A person interested in being a mod posts an answer featuring username and the link to the profile, plus an optional why-me text.
- Nominating someone else is not allowed. Better poke this user on chat and ask to consider starting.
- Users express their support/negation by voting, and support words/doubts as comments.
- SE team will use the results as a tip who to select.

Answer (score 9):

My name is [Alexander Galkin](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/66/alexander-galkin) (it is my real name, so is the photo on my avatar).

I hold a medial degree with summa cum lauda from Kazan Medical University and I have spent 8 years in total working as a researcher in neuroscience, cognitive science, pharmacology, biochemistry and computer simulation of single neurons and neuronal networks. The latter inspired me to study computer science and I am about to graduate from Hamburg University of Technology with the degree of Dipl. Ing. in Computer Science.

I am an experienced (1.5yr) StackExchange user with almost 2k reputation on the main [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376692/alexander-galkin) site and prominent presence on some other sides, like [German Language](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1034/alexander-galkin), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40805/alexander-galkin) etc.

I love answering questions and helping people and I will do my best to make our site a decent member of the StackExchange stack.

I don't have moderator experience on SE, but I have been moderator for already about 10 years on other popular forums, for example on this [Esperanto-forum](http://e-novosti.info/forumo/).

Comment: +1 Support candidacy.

Comment: +1 I hope you become a mod, as real name mods who showed expertise will attract more experts from outside.

Answer (score 7):

I'll go ahead and nominate myself ([Mad Scientist](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/6/mad-scientist)).

I'm one of the pro-tem mods on Skeptics, so I have some experience in moderating an SE site.

Comment: +1 Support candidacy.

Answer (score 6):

[mbq](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/59/mbq)

I'm an elected moderator on Stats and Physics so I have some experience; I'm in favor of a broad scope, I consider clean look a factor improving quality (thus I often edit stuff) and I think policies should grow organically rather than be designed *a priori*.

I live in the CET zone.

Comment: +1 Support candidacy.

Comment: +1 mbq is an excellent mod over on Stats

Comment: Thanks for writing about your position in some common questions. The moderators affect policy a lot, even if not on purpose.

Comment: while I agree with your statement, is it a good idea to become mod on 3 very brought and tricky topics? Do you really have time and expertise with 25 for discussion of tricky questions and problems on meta on 3 sites? Sorry but nobody has very broad and detailed scope in physics and biology with 25 if at all, I would rather like to see a mod focusing on the very broad biology site without other tasks

Comment: @WernerSchmitt Even with 199 no-one would have expertise to solve all thematic problems on even single site -- that's why this is a community's burden, moderators are rather janitors that clean, fix small problems and occasionally organize something. About time, CV and Physics are grown-ups and peaceful places; single SO mod does 10x work that I do now.

Answer (score 4):

- [Biology Profile](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/69/rory)
- [Meta Profile](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/users/69/rory)

Sorry I'm a bit late with this.

I wasn't originally going to put myself forward as I am quite new to the StackExchange platform.  However I have really very much enjoyed working with you all to help build the site over the last few days and feel that I would be able to give a lot!  I have been active on the main site every day but one and have also tried to help in discussions on meta.

A little about me, I'm taking my final A-Level exams later this year (including biology, of course!) and assuming that all goes well will be taking up my place at medical school.  So, whilst I may be still amassing a knowledge base, I would hope to be useful to the community in the years to come. I say years because I think it's important for mods to be in it for the long haul in order to build a relationship with other frequent users!

Whilst I don't have any previous moderating experience on StackExchange, I was a moderator for nearly three years on a tech support forum with in excess of 400,000 members and believe I learnt a lot from that experience.  I certainly believe that I would be well suited to introducing new experts to the SE platform and hopefully encouraging them to stay.  I am a native English speaker and member of [SE English](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15881/rory?tab=summary) and have made a fair few edits here that have hopefully made things a little clearer and more consistently formatted (20 edits approved, more in the queue).

All in all I would love to take a leading role in the creation, development and [promotion](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/materials-for-the-beta-promotion/77#77) of the SE Biology site.  Whatever the outcome, I look forward to working alongside everyone in the community!

Comment: What does "A-level exams" mean?

Comment: Sorry, they're the English "Further Education" level exams, I guess they could be viewed universally as university entrance exams?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCE_Advanced_Level

Answer (score 3):

[Poshpaws](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/81/poshpaws)

I  have a strong interest in seeing this site be successful. I also believe in moderation and respect at all times, and like to try and encourage citations where appropriate.

I also confess that I had to look up what "Pro Tempore" means.