# Materials for the beta promotion?

Tags: discussion, promotion, site-promotion

As it has been already discussed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-it-ok-to-promote-the-site-during-the-beta), promotion of the beta site is not only allowed, it is much welcome in the community.

In order to be able to successfully promote the site we need good materials. Here are some examples of what I would appreciate much to have online or available for download:

1. One page summary with the goals, the do's and dont's of the site, including the clear statement what kind of questions are welcome and what might be off-topic for this site (clear medical questions etc.).
2. One graphical or text-based banner with a link to the page and some appealing motto or slogan.
3. A4 print-friendly version of the flyer, best if foldable, containing the same information as in the first point with all links and probably some interesting sample questions with answers *á la* "Did you know?" etc (if appropriate).

The original text needs to be written or at least corrected by a native speaker of English. Translations to other mainstream languages are welcome, I promise to translate all materials into German and Russian.

Now, the questions:
1. Do you support this idea?
2. Do you have other ideas concerning the materials we might need or produce?
3. Anybody volunteering for writing the original texts/banners/flyer and for translations in other languages?

Comment: More than happy to do the English proofing and produce a few banners if I'm given a clear brief =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: 1st Banner Draft]

[image: 2nd Banner Draft]

[image: 3rd Banner Draft]

[image: 4th Banner Draft]

All very very rough, we really need to decide on proper wording for the tag-line.  Does anyone know for sure the position with using "Stack Exchange" in promo materials?  I'm assuming it's okay =S

Comment: Great! Thanks! I will try to use them.

Comment: No problem, they're really rough and I'd welcome feedback *from everyone* so we can get more polished ones worked out =D

Answer (score 1):

And for **point 1 on your list**, I'll put this as Community Wiki so we can all contribute:

---

**StackExchange Biology:** A new question and answer site for experts in the field of biology.  Currently looking for new academics, researchers, physicians and university students to participate in discussion of topics including:

- High level human physiology
- In depth bio-chemistry
- Breaking molecular biology topics
- Interesting neuroscience and genetics questions

Some recent hot questions:

- [Why did the process of sleep evolve in many animals? What is its evolutionary advantage](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/324/why-did-the-process-of-sleep-evolve-in-many-animals-what-is-its-evolutionary-ad)?
- [Is there any evidence that sexual selection may lead to the extinction of species](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/239/is-there-any-evidence-that-sexual-selection-may-lead-to-extinction-of-species)?
- [How are the boundaries of a gene determined](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/228/how-are-the-boundaries-of-a-gene-determined)?
- [Is telomere length a reliable measure of health/lifespan](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/186/is-telomere-length-a-reliable-measure-of-health-lifespan)?
- [Why is uracil used in RNA rather than thymine](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/171/why-is-uracil-used-in-rna-rather-than-thymine)?
- *[See More](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)*

Come and visit our welcoming, focussed and up to the minute community at http://biology.stackexchange.com

---

Really encourage *everyone* to post comments, edit the text, make changes & improvements, translate, whatever will help us get more traffic to the site =)